# dangerouslySetInnerHTML not displaying h1, h2. h3,... tags

Tags: reactjs, next.js, markdown

In a NextJS + Tailwind project I'm trying to read markdown content.

All tags like strong, italic, etc. work, but not the headings.
Same result with parse from "html-react-parser" library, ex

```
{parse("<h1>single</h1>")}

 // Or

<div
  dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: "<h1>This is a heading</h1>",}}
/>
```

Thanks for your help.

**Solution:**

i found this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70915406/tailwind-typography-plugin-doesnt-change-font-style-of-heading-tags-from-defaul?rq=2) that worked as needed

```
h1 {
  @apply text-3xl;
}
h2 {
  @apply text-2xl;
}
h3 {
  @apply text-xl;
}
a {
  @apply text-blue-600 underline;
}
```